# Connecting/Binding Two QML Properties in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I would like to programmatically set a binding from one QML object to another in C++ when one QML has been created programmatically.

I have a custom qml object `Boxxy` defined in `Boxxy.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    property double bScale: 1.0
    color:"red"
    height: 50
    width: 100*bScale
}
```

I then use it as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    property  var mainObj: main
    property double viewScale : 1.0

    width: 640; height: 480
    visible: true

    Rectangle{
        id:main
        anchors.fill:parent

        Boxxy{           
            y: 75; height: 50;
            bScale:viewScale
        }
    }
}
```

Because my actually code has extensive existing logic and controllers in c++, I want to create some elements programmatically and then connect them in manually. In this example, I want to set `bScale` property to the parent control's `viewScale` property.

I create a `Boxxy` in c++ with:

```
    QObject * root = engine.rootObjects()[0];
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/Boxxy.qml"));
    QQuickItem*  main = qvariant_cast<QQuickItem*>(root->property("mainObj"));
    auto * box = (QQuickItem*)component.create();
    box->setParent(main);
    box->setParentItem(main);
```

but then the `bScale` is not connected to the `viewScale`. I hoped to do

```
QObject::connect(root, SIGNAL("viewScaleChanged()"), box, SLOT("bScale"));
```

How can I duplicate the binding of the two properties in c++?

Comment: I don't really understand your architecture. It seems to take all fun and simplicity out of QML by building it all in C++. In that case, maybe Qt Widgets would be more straightforward?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a property binding in Qt/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842557/how-to-create-a-property-binding-in-qt-c)

Comment: @JarMan The architecture is there because  we want to leverage existing code while using the modern interface, transitions, and customizability of qml as much as possible. Qt Widgets has some animations and customizability but lacks the extensive and optimized and smooth interface of qml, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that this solution works when your QML types are created in QML the usual way.
Rewrite your `Boxxy` as follow:

```
Item {
    id: name
    property real bScale: 1.0
    Rectangle {
        color:"red"
        height: 50
        width: 100 * parent.bScale
    }
}
```

Also in your code when ever `viewScale` changes `bScale` will update itself. To be sure, make your code work in pure qml. Then try C++ back-end approach.

Or maybe just a simple [Repeater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) is enough for you.